# DAO when to use suspend function android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am following DAO tutorial on Android developers here:

https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin#5

They say: 
By default, all queries must be executed on a separate thread.
Room has Kotlin coroutines support. This allows your queries to be annotated with the suspend modifier and then called from a coroutine or from another suspension function.

Dao interface is as follows:

```
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): List<Word>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

Why `getAlphabetizedWords()` is not defined as suspend function?

Comment: It seems they did it intentionally, in the next chapter it will be changed to `Flow` to observe changes.

Comment: thank you for asking this question, I myself was searching for that kind of tutorial, and now I found it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In coroutines, a flow is a type that can emit multiple values sequentially, as opposed to suspend functions that return only a single value. For example, you can use a flow to receive live updates from a database.

```java
@Dao
interface WordDao {

    // The flow always holds/caches latest version of data. Notifies its observers when the
    // data has changed.
    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY word ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<Word>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(word: Word)

    @Query("DELETE FROM word_table")
    suspend fun deleteAll()
}
```

you can see [source code](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-room-with-a-view/blob/kotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/roomwordssample/WordDao.kt) in Github.

Comment: Thank you @TanZhenxing I can get the concept now.

Comment: This makes no sense. I wanna fetch all the data with suspend and Room just disallows it?! Another nonsense by Google